# Error while trying to install flash plugin through software center

Tags: flash, plugins

Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.1.102.63-0oneiric1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.1.102.63-0oneiric1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command line and execute `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` to install the latest version of the flash player.